# How to install seleniumHQ for Python on Windows?

Tags: windows, installation, python

I would like to know how to install [SeleniumHQ](http://seleniumhq.org/download/) on Windows XP/Vista/7?

On Ubuntu/Debian system you need to just type those commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
$ sudo pip install selenium
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip xvfb xserver-xephyr
$ sudo pip install selenium
```

and then I can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from selenium import selenium
# ...
```

but how about Windows? Thanks for any help (I know where to find Selenium doc but still - would anybody be so kind to give me some steps: I mean, download this, do that ...)

Comment: Anybody ... ? Please I really dont know how to do this geez Im an idiot :/

Comment: @HackToHell: Ok, done ;)

Comment: @HackToHell: oh I noticed this +2 rep, its soo nice, thanks again ^^ I will remember to do this :* :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I finally did it but not at all. I just installed seleniumHQ:

1. Download the last pip version from here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip#downloads
2. Uncompress it
3. Download the last easy installer for Windows: (download the .exe at the bottom of http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools ). Install it.
4. Go to the uncompressed pip directory and: python setup.py install
5. Add your python c:\Python2x\Scripts to the path
6. Run cmd.exe and type: pip install -U selenium

and I can finally type:

```
python
>> from selenium import selenium
>>
```

and it works, yay! But still have problems with installing this:

```
xvfb xserver-xephyr
```

On Ubuntu/Debian OS I just need to type:

`sudo apt-get install python-pip xvfb xserver-xephyr`

and it works but how about Windows?

**EDIT:**

You cant install xvfb xserver-xephyr on Windows but You can install splinter which is a SeleniumHQ nice wrapper, you can install it by typing:

```
pip install splinter
```

thats all, good luck :)